# Swift: How to call a category or class method from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-category

I have a category on `UIImage` that is written in Objective-C.  The following are some example methods.  How do I call these methods in Swift?

```
+(UIImage *) imageOrPDFNamed:(NSString *)resourceName; 
+(UIImage *) imageWithPDFNamed:(NSString *)resourceName;
```

I have tried the following and it does not recognize the methods:

```
let image = UIImage(imageOrPDFNamed:"test.pdf")
let image = UIImage(PDFNamed:"test.pdf")
```

Comment: These are class methods; `UIImage.image...`

Comment: Also make sure you've `#import`ed the category's header in your bridging header.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are various cases for categories function and it's calling conventions.

1)In `swift` class functions in categories can be imported as `convenience initializes` if they returned same type on which they called like

```
 +(UIImage *) imageOrPDFNamed:(NSString *)resourceName ;
```

so it can be called as

```
    UIImage(orPDFNamed: "abc")
```

2)However if class functions in categories are not returning same object type(`UIImage`) on which it calls in this case `UIImage` like

```
   +(int) imageOrPDFNamedInt:(NSString *)resourceName ;
```

it will called as

```
    UIImage.imageOrPDFNamedInt("abc")
```

3)If categories function is not class function so it will call as directly on instance of `UIImage` like

```
   -(UIImage *) imagePDFNamed:(NSString *)resourceName ;
```

called as

```
    UIImage().imagePDFNamed("abc")
```

Comment: This didn't work, but your answer helped me find the solution in the sense that after entering your suggested code, Xcode said this method is not available and then suggested the code that I am showing in my answer.

Comment: @RawMean thanks for pointing that actually i have ignored on which it is called.Sorry for that.Howerver i have edited my answer it will further clarifies how to call category function in swift.

Comment: Your answer before the "edit" is still incorrect.  I'd like to accept your answer if you can remove the bit before the "Edit"

Comment: Good answer. Seems that if your category class method is something like `+ (NSDate *)dateWithTimestamp:(NSString *)timestamp` then the convenience initializer assumes the "with" as well, so it is called like this: `NSDate(timestamp:timestampString)`. That seems less than obvious, and it is unclear to me why I can't just use `NSDate.dateWithTimestamp(...)` if I want to. Convenience initializers are not a convenience if they're mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

This is finally what worked:

```
let image = UIImage(orPDFNamed:"test.pdf")
```