# How to override a oc category method in .swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a OC  `UIViewController` category , which decleared a class method of `UIViewController`

```
+(BOOL)hasStoryBoard;
```

And I also import this category into `xxx-Bridging-Header.h` file

My swift class `CustomVC` is inherited UIViewController. I want override `+(BOOL)hasStoryBoard` to give a BOOL-type value.This method will called in other class to determine  `CustomVC`'s new instance's some feature.

But in my CustomVC.swift I cannot find method like this:

`override class func hasStoryBoard()->bool{}`

I must override this method to give a `YES`,or give it's subclass a `NO`,so on...

I searched this site and find this [Swift: How to call a category or class method from Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089142/swift-how-to-call-a-category-or-class-method-from-objective-c). In this discussion , explained and tell you how to call the method,not how to override the method .

Can you find solution to **override oc category's class method?** Or give a workaround in my case.

**All my code is :**

```
@interface UIViewController (StoryBoard)
+(BOOL)hasStoryBoard;
-(void)haha;
@end
```

.

```
@implementation UIViewController (StoryBoard)

static BOOL hasStoryboard = NO;//默认没有
+(BOOL)hasStoryBoard{
    return hasStoryboard;
}
-(void)haha{}
@end
```

.

```
class CustomVC: UIViewController {
    //this override is correct,have syntax input prompt

    override func haha() {

    }
    //this override is incorrect ,no syntax input prompt

    override func hasStoryBoard()->Bool{
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you import the category header in the bridging header ?

Comment: @deadbeef I did , and I test OC category's instance method can be found in .swift file ,but OC category's class method cannot be found in .swift file.This has be mentioned in above link , but question is `how to override`?

Comment: What error do you get if you implement the override anyway ? `override class func hasStoryBoard() -> Bool { return true }`

Comment: `Method does not override any method from its superclass`

Comment: Any chance there is a typo somewhere ? It should work...

Comment: Please add Objective-C code and Swift subclass code.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(BOOL)hasStoryBoard;
```

defines a *class* method in Objective-C, but in your Swift subclass
you define an *instance* method:

```
override func hasStoryBoard()->Bool{
    return true
}
```

That must be a class method as well:

```
override class func hasStoryBoard()->Bool{
    return true
}
```

---

*Tip:* If you open the Objective-C interface (.h) file in Xcode and
select "Navigate->Jump to Generated Interface" from the Xcode menu
then you'll see excacly how the Objective-C interface is imported to
Swift. In your case:

```
extension UIViewController {
    open class func hasStoryBoard() -> Bool
    open func haha()
}
```

Now you can copy the function definition and use it to define
the overriding method in your subclass.